# Apply Calibri (Body) font to text

Tags: css, html, font-family

I have a div and in this div I want to display some text in Calibri (Body) font.

How can I do this?

This is the css I have been given :

```
.an_account_join_1 {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    color:#000000;
    font-family:Calibri (Body);
    letter-spacing:2px;
    font-size:14px;
    text-align:center;
    margin:20px 0px;
    }
```

This is the div:

```
<div class="an_account_join_1">Individual Free Membership</div>
```

There is no font style displayed with this font family.

When I look at the firebug output there is no style for font family.

Answer (score -9, accepted):

If there is a space between the letters of the font, you need to use quote.

```
font-family:"Calibri (Body)";
```

Answer (score 104):

There is no such font as “Calibri (Body)”. You probably saw this string in Microsoft Word font selection menu, but it’s not a font name (see e.g. the explanation [Font: +body (in W07)](http://www.techtalkz.com/microsoft-office/84726-font-body-w07.html)).

So use just `font-family: Calibri` or, better, `font-family: Calibri, sans-serif`. (There is no adequate backup font for Calibri, but the odds are that when Calibri is not available, the browser’s default sans-serif font suits your design better than the browser’s default font, which is most often a serif font.)

Answer (score 5):

change the font type for div use

```
.an_account_join_1{
font-family:"Calibri", sans-serif;
}
```

for the main menu in WordPress

```
#primary-menu{
    font-family:"Calibri", sans-serif;
    }
```